# No pushing of a local Mercurial commits to SVN with HgSubversion?

Tags: mercurial, push, hgsubversion

I am making say 4 local commits in HgSVN, then I updated my local code to an earlier revision, I added changes to it, did local commits, merged with server code and when tried to push, I was not allowed because of the 4 local commits not merged.

1. How to delete/remove these 4 local commits from HgSVN history and push the code ?
2. What should be done in this scenario ?

   - using HgCommit for saving code to the local machine and
   - HgWorkbench for pushing the local changes to the server
   - [image: using HgCommit for saving code to the local machine and HgWorkbench for pushing the local changes to the server]

Comment: local commits & push are not terms that seem to relate to subversion. Are you talking about using two separate repositories?

Comment: @crashmstr: I am using HgCommit and HgWorkbench for submitting locally(local commits) and to server(push) respectively.

Comment: This does not seem like normal workflow.  HgCommit  would be Mercurial, I assume.  So is this a Mercurial question or tortoise?  If you're mixing the two, isn't that asking for trouble?

Comment: @ppu you really need to change your tags and title, since your question now reads *very* differently.

Comment: @crashmstr : made the tag change hope its the right one.

Comment: I voted for closing this question, because it has serious quality problems: poorly formulated, doesn't contain mandatory data (log of commands, glog output or screenshot of DAG), used not-conventional terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main big problem: you prefer do nor read docs and use tools blindly. Otherwise you have to know one of the biggest limitation of HgSubversion: it is not possible to push back to Subversion mergesets from Mercurial

"...[Mercurial merges cannot be pushed to Subversion](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/src/tip/hgsubversion/help/subversion.rst)"

Also, [HgSubversion page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion) on Mercurial wiki clearly states:

> The important point to note is that hgsubversion cannot push merge changesets to a svn repository. This means you should **not** try to merge this new head -- if you do so, hg push to svn will fail. Instead, you should rebase the changesets that you want to push to the Subversion repository (see *Rebasing changes* below)